# What kinds of injuries are covered by Social Security?

Tags: united-states, disabilities, americans-with-disabilities-act, social-security, accident-insurance

I am injured ([by sports injury](https://www.google.com/maps/reviews/@40.226143,-74.010427,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!14m4!1m3!1m2!1s116647982166856941576!2s0x0:0x378cebad53d3cd2f?hl=en-US)) but was [called schizophrenic](https://www.google.com/maps/reviews/@40.3536779,-74.0639766,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!14m4!1m3!1m2!1s116647982166856941576!2s0x0:0xfe73b6ff732230da?hl=en-US).  I am a bartender, otherwise I will not take fraud as income. For this I looked into the 2018 National Beneficiary Survey (next one estimated release 2023) that says of 4062 reporters **35.4% are mentally ill, 5.2% with developmental disability, and 14.9% are injured** (or poisoned) in 2015. For a picture of the **Musculoskeletally-disordered of 42.1%**, we can use the [Center on Budget and Policy Priorities](https://www.cbpp.org/research/social-security/social-security-disability-insurance-0) [reports](https://www.cbpp.org/typical-disabled-worker-is-over-50-and-has-severe-mental-musculoskeletal-or-other-impairment-2) to get an age-related image. So, other than age, what injuries constitute a proper claim? Is it only when something (1) falls on you (2) on the job?

[image: Center on Budget and Policy Priorities]

[image: National Beneficiary Survey, 2015]

Comment: Social security covers a disability that sometimes results from an injury. It doesn't cover the injury itself.

Answer (score 3):

The Social Security Administration only provides benefits for what has been termed as *total disability*, which can be broadly described as the long-term, indefinite ability to work. Short-term injuries, which impair your ability to work for a finite period, or impair your ability to perform your current job but would still allow you to work generally, are covered by benefits such as short-term disability insurance and/or unemployment.

From the [SSA web site](https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/disability/qualify.html#anchor2):

> We consider you to have a qualifying disability under Social Security
> rules if all the following are true:
>
> - You cannot do work and engage in substantial gainful activity (SGA)
>   because of your medical condition.
> - You cannot do work you did
>   previously or adjust to other work because of your medical condition.
> - Your condition has lasted or is expected to last for at least one year
>   or to result in death.
>
> This is a strict definition of disability. Social Security program rules assume that working families have access to other resources to provide support during periods of short-term disabilities, including workers' compensation, insurance, savings, and investments.